# Frequency analysis

Tags: cryptanalysis, randomness, substitution-cipher

In a way or another, a text is encoded based on a alphabet layout;
What if the layout is scrambled (based on a key) for every plain char (scramble layout, encode D, scramble, encode A etc) ?
The frequency analysis is equally effective ? Thank you.

Comment: This will be closed as off-topic, due to the request to analyze a cipher. But as a rule of tumb:  Any manual cipher can easily be broken by a computer. Your scheme is vulnerable to frequency analysis, just a little more complex than regular ceasar cipher.

Comment: so, keep the message short :)

Comment: If we interpret "resist a computer" as *actual security in today's sense*, you are not going to get that from a handmade cipher, it's that simple.  I would consider this weaker than Vigenere, but I suggest reading up on [cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptanalysis) in general, and see what today's point of view is.

Comment: To begin with, a repeated char is decrypted as plain char, ex 'DD' pair in cithertext is obviously 'D' in plaintext.

Comment: @kludg        you are right, but considering a 'handmade' encoding, alice can avoid pairs :)

Comment: With the edit you just made it "too broad to answer", by deleting the details. And you don't have stated any goal anymore. With "strong enough to resist a computer" you could actually get an answer, even if it wasn't to your liking.

Answer (score 4):

My answer won't please you but we don't analyze cipher here. Your design is interesting in term of pen and paper, but might still be sensible to statistical analysis given a long enough cipher text.

This is basically the same answer as [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/37380/29161).

You are assuming a **weak attacker**: it has **only access to the cipher text**.

In cryptography, we consider a **strong attacker**: he has **full access to the algorithm** and he **can try to encrypt as many plaintext as he wants**. The idea is to be able to retrieve the key in order to decrypt the initial cipher text.

The scenario is the following:

```
1. Eve has intercepted an encrypted message from Alice.
   She can't read it.

2. During lunch, she access Alice's computer.
   For some reason she can not decipher the message.
   But she can encrypt many more messages so she will be able to attack the key later.

3. With all this encrypted message (with the same key) Eve can find the encryption key.

4. With this encryption key, she can now decrypt the initial message.
```

This is the usual assumption. In your case you only need to encrypt something like *AAA...A B...B C....Y Z...Z*. At some point you will have returned all the combinations of the table, inducing the break of your cipher.

Comment: 'we consider a strong attacker...During lunch, she access Alice's computer' = without computer, encryption is better ?

Comment: That's not the point. The point is, you have to consider [known plaintext attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) at the very least to be considered secure today. And follow [Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), in that the attacker knows the encryption scheme. And from that, the attacker can reconstruct your table with one pair of ciphertext/plaintext quite likely.

Comment: I will add for step #2, an attacker can easilly copy the program that generate the encrypted text to be able to know the encryption method. For a computer analyst its easier than you think. (offtopic there, but kinda the same way than a reverse engeneer produce keygen for an app, by analising the algorith for the key validation)